# IntelliSense not working even after settings are applied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

[Seems like duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/intellisense-not-working-but-it-is-enabled) but it isn't. I have tried every answers exception being accepted one as I did not upgraded visual studio.

Product is **SQL Server 2012.**

My settings

1. Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact SQL > Intellisense > Enable Intellisense is checked, Max script size is set to unlimited.
2. Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact SQL > General > Auto list members is checked and so is Parameter Information.
3. Query > IntelliSense Enabled option is selected and disabled.
4. Query > SQLCMD Mode not selected.
5. Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache clicked many times.

Still couldn't get IntelliSense enabled. Seems like installation issue? re-installed already but no luck.

Comment: "Query > IntelliSense Enabled option is selected and disabled." Do you mean that it is **enabled**? If it is disabled, then you won't see Intellisense when editing that query.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I am it is enable by default but I can't disable it as option is grayed out.